# Limit fulltext search in MariaDB (innodb)

Tags: mariadb, full-text-search, query-optimization, innodb

I'm having trouble making a search on a fairly large (5 million entries) table fast.

This is innodb on MariaDB (10.4.25).

Structure of the table `my_table` is like so:

| id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | some text |
| 2 | some more text |

I now have a fulltext index on "text" and search for:

`SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE MATCH ('text') AGAINST ("some* tex*" IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

This is not super slow but can yield to millions of results. Retrieving them in my Java application takes forever but I need the matching ids.

Therefore, I wanted to limit the number already by the ids I know can only be relevant and tried something like this (id is primary index):

`SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE id IN (1,2) AND MATCH ('text') AGAINST ("some* tex*" IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

hoping that it would first limit to the 2 ids and then apply the fulltext search and give me the two results super quickly. Alas, that's not what happened and I don't understand why.

How can I limit the query if I already know some ids to only search through those AND make the query faster by doing so?

Comment: "Alas, that's not what happened and I don't understand why."  It's really unclear what did happen.

Comment: @Luuk what happened was that id did *not* use the primary index to filter down millions of results to 2 and then apply the match like I hoped

Comment: So the output was unexpected because.....  It would be great to include that kind of information in your question, an not let the reader guess about what happened.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `FULLTEXT` (or `SPATIAL`) index together with some 'regular' index, the Optimizer assumes that the former will run faster, so it does that first.

Furthermore, it is nontrivial (maybe impossible) to run `MATCH` against a subset of a table.

Both of those conspire to say that the `MATCH` will happen *first*.  (Of course, you were hoping to do the opposite.)

Is there a workaround?  I doubt it.  Especially if there a lot of rows with words starting with 'some' or 'tex'.

One thing to try is "+":

```
MATCH ('text') AGAINST ("+some* +tex*" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Please report back whether this helped.

Hmmmm... Perhaps you want

```
MATCH (`text`)   -- this
MATCH ('text')   -- NOT this
```

There are two features in MariaDB:

- max time spent in query
- max number of rows *accessed* (may not apply to FULLTEXT)

Comment: you're right, I do want the index on id to be used first - but you say I can't force that?
I actually do use `text` - just did't work with the markdown here
the + really speeds things up considerably but the semantics are of course not the same anymore

Comment: My point is that the query cannot be processed if `FULLTEXT` if it starts by using `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.  Can't win.  Forcing it (if possible) will probably make the query run slower.  You can try it with `FORCE(PRIMARY)`.  Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` of your attempts.